# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError - FeatureIDE CLI Tool

Tags: java, classnotfoundexception

I am trying to use the CLI Tool of FeatureIDE to generate samples from a feature model.

I am a total newb, when it comes to JAVA. I downloaded the .jar from the GitHub Repository of FeatureIDE. When I try to invoke the .jar from CLI I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/antlr/runtime/RecognitionException
        at de.ovgu.featureide.fm.core.init.FMCoreLibrary.install(FMCoreLibrary.java:81)
        at de.ovgu.featureide.fm.core.init.LibraryManager.registerLibrary(LibraryManager.java:53)
        at de.ovgu.featureide.fm.core.cli.FeatureIDECLI.main(FeatureIDECLI.java:45)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.antlr.runtime.RecognitionException
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
        ... 3 more
```

I do understand that `org.antlr.runtime.RecognitionException` is missing, but I am totally unsure how to resolve this issue.

Can anybody maybe give me a hint on how I can get rid of this error?

I need to use this tool for my thesis, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Regards
Peter

Comment: You need to include another jar - or if you use maven a dependency.

Comment: I think I solved it by adding a "lib" directory which contains the missing .jar Files. Thank You